# Big-O and Function Domination

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am currently working on some problems from my textbook, about Big-O notation, and how functions can dominate each other.

These are the functions that I am looking at from my book.

1. `n²`
2. `n² + 1000n`
3. `n` (if `n` is odd)
   `n³` (if `n` is even)
4. `n` (if `n ≤ 100`) 
   `n³` (if `n > 100`)

I am trying to figure out which functions that #1 dominates. I know that both #1 and #2 simplify to `n²`, so it does not dominate #2. However, the split functions (#3 and #4) are giving me problems. #1 dominates the function only on a certain condition, and under the other condition, #1 is being dominated by the other function. So does this mean that, since it is not always dominating it, that it doesn't technically count as dominating it at all? Does function #1 not dominate any of these functions, or does it dominate #3, for all odd numbers, and #4 for all numbers ≤ 100? The way I see it is, #1 does not dominate #2, only dominates #3 for odd numbers, and only dominates #4 for numbers  ≤ 100. Am I on the right track?

Thanks for any help anyone can provide. I'm having a real tough time trying to reason this out to myself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what "dominates" means in your case. Lets say "`f(n)` dominates `g(n)`" translates to `f(n) ∈ O(g(n))`, where `O(g(n))` is the worst case complexity.

So we should calculate the worst case complexity first:

- `n²` is in `Θ(n²)`
- `n² + 1000n` is also in `Θ(n²)`
- `n` (if `n` is odd) `n³` (if `n` is even) is in `Θ(n³)` (just picking the worst case which appears in 50% of all cases for random choices of `n`)
- `n` (if `n ≤ 100`) `n³` (if `n > 100`) is also in `Θ(n³)`, since Big-O depends on asymptotics (large values of `n`).

Now we can compare the worst case complexities and see #1 dominates only #2.

Maybe you want to change the worst case complexity to an average case. But only for #3 there could be a change.
After calculating `(n³ + n) / 2` we notice, that even the average case of #3 is in `Θ(n³)`.

If you look at the best case you get the first change, but also only for #3. Here the best case is `Θ(n)`, so here is #3 dominated by #1.

Notice that the best case of #4 is not `Θ(n)`, since the complexity holds only for `n → ∞`, so we ignore all cases of `n < c₀` where `c₀` is a constant.